# What does ~HEAD (tilde Head) mean in tortoisegit?

Tags: branch, tortoisegit

Recently I have started to see some weird things when I want to commit using TortoiseGit. The following screenshot is taken from the commit UI of TortoiseGit:

[image]

In this image, you can see the files finishing by ~HEAD

or ~CommitNumber + description of the commit.

What does it mean?

Do I need to be worried?

What should I do, or what have I done wrong?

I don't know if it's relevant but those files are supposed to be deleted.

Comment: maybe some temp files from viewing rev diffs. Which diff tool do you use?

Comment: I'm using TortoiseGit.

Comment: this is the client, but which Diff tool? KDiff3? WinMerge? TortoiseMerge?

Comment: Yes it's tortoiseMerge. This is the tortoiseGit default one.

Comment: These files are definitely not created by TortoiseGit. TortoiseGit writes all temporary files into %TMP%\TortoiseGit